# Two samples with median of 0, mood's test give p-value of very close to 0. How to interpret this?

Tags: nonparametric

First of all I would like to say I'm unfamiliar with the Mood's test so pardon me if the question is too basic.

I'm trying to compare the difference of median between two groups of data. I did some prelim test first and see that both groups have the same median of 0. These two group have different sample sizes (60k vs 30k observation)

However, my Mood's test in R gives me a p-value of nearly 0 (2.53e-08 to be specific), which I assume mean my two medians are different. So how does this happen when both of my sample's medians are 0 ?

I have a lot of samples that I want to compare medians together so should I just ignore samples where I found the median to be 0? Thank you.

Comment: Would help to show actual counts in the four cells of the table for the application of Mood's test with the answer that puzzles you. Depending on the data, it might be useful to know how many observations in each group fall _exactly_ at the median. So please show that also.

Comment: Be sure not to confuse Mood's median test with Mood's test of scale.

Answer (score 5):

Here is an example that may be sufficiently similar to yours
for a helpful explanation. My two groups have the same sample
sizes, which are much smaller than the sample sizes in your
problem. But the fundamental idea should be clear. Different distributions can produce samples that
have the same median.

Two groups `x1` and `x2` each have 50 observations (consisting of integers from 1 through 5), tabled in R
as follows:

```
table(x1);  table(x2)
x1
 1  2  3  4  5 
 3 15 23  4  5

table(x2) 
x2
 1  2  3  4  5 
 5  1 36  5  3
```

It is easy to see that the two samples each have median 3,
as verified in R below.

```
median(x1); median(x2)
[1] 3
[1] 3
```

To do Mood's median test on two samples you can make a two-by-two
table of these data. The first row is for the first sample
and the second row is for the second sample. The first entry
in each row is the number of outcomes at or above the median.

Put the samples in to a table, as appropriate for input for the
relevant `chisq.test` in R, and run the test:

```
TAB = rbind(c(18, 32), c(7, 46))
TAB
     [,1] [,2]
[1,]   18   32
[2,]    7   46

chisq.test(TAB, cor=F)

        Pearson's Chi-squared test

data:  TAB
X-squared = 7.2716, df = 1, p-value = 0.007005
```

While both samples of size 50 have median 3, notice that
the first sample has 18 of its 50 observations below 3, while
the second sample only has 7 of its observations below 3.
Thus the two samples are from significantly different populations.

Making a `barplot` of each sample may help to illustrate that Sample 1 has proportionately more large values than does Sample 2.

```
par(mfrow=c(1,2))
 barplot(c(3,15,23,4,5), xlab="Sample 1", names.arg=1:5)
 barplot(c(5,1,36,5,3), xlab="Sample 2", names.arg=1:5)
par(mfrow=c(1,2))
```

[image]

*Note:* The following R code was used to get the two samples.
The `p` vectors show the relative proportions of numbers 1 through 5 should be randomly sampled for each.

```
set.seed(1234)
x1 = sample(1:5, 50, rep=T, p = c(1,2,4,1,1))
x2 = sample(1:5, 50, rep=T, p = c(1,1,5,1,1))
```

Comment: Awesome, thank you. The example is very straight to the point and is exactly what I need.

Comment: The 'mood.test' function performs Mood's test of scale, not Mood's median test !!!  For example compare results: `if(!require(RVAideMemoire)){install.packages("RVAideMemoire")}; if(!require(coin)){install.packages("coin")}; library(coin); library(RVAideMemoire); y1 = rnorm(16, 1, 1); y2 = rnorm(16, 8, 1); mood.test(y1, y2); y = c(y1,y2); group = factor(c(rep("Y1", length(y1)), rep("Y2", length(y2)))); mood.medtest(x = y, g=group); median_test(y ~ group); plot(y ~ group)`

Comment: @SalMangiafico. I was just answering the question how it is possible to get significant test stat with `mood.test` when sample medians are equal. I was not recommending use of the Mood test here or elsewhere. It has notoriously poor power.

Comment: You might have missed my point. The function `mood.test` doesn't perform a median test at all.  It's a different test. (And actually the question doesn't specify this function).  There are options for functions to perform a median test in my comment.

Comment: OK. Mood's _median_ test, which I assumed I was doing before, can be done in R as a chi-squared test using a $2 \times 2$ table, as explained in my revised answer. The slightly different data are are from a different simulation. Thanks for noting the discrepancy. [The part of your Answer that states, "[W]hy not equal to and less than? Because with truly continuous data, the choice is arbitrary. But with your data it may matter. Try multiplying your data by -1 and see if that affects results..." is relevant here; hence the change in data.]

Comment: I just want to clarify @SalMangiafico that such function isn't what I used. I use mood.median.test() from library MultNonParam so based on the explicit name I assume it does test median not distribution.

Answer (score 3):

Mood's median test gets funky in some cases and shouldn't be used in those situations.  It sounds like you have two samples with the same median which is  also equal to the pooled median.  The first thing to say is that it would be ridiculous to say that two samples have statistically different medians when they have numerically the same median.   That's a statistical test you just don't need to perform. Another way to look at it, since you have so many values equal to the median, your data isn't truly continuous, and the test isn't really appropriate.  Mood's median test does an interesting thing where it counts values equal to and greater than the pooled mean (I think, usually) in the same group.  But why not equal to and *less than*?  Because with truly continuous data, the choice is arbitrary.  But with your data it may matter.  Try multiplying your data by -1 and see if that affects results...

So, what to do?  I think if you care about the medians, you have your answer.  Both samples have the same median, so you don't need to test anything.  If you are curious about other properties of the samples, you may want to look at other quantiles (e.g. the 75th percentile, by quantile regression or permutation test).  Or maybe the stochastic differences in the samples by Wilconon-Mann-Whitney.